# IMPORTRANGE #REF! Error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm trying to run a query (IMPORTRANGE) formula in a new Google sheet. The data I'm trying to load is from another sheet. The source sheet contains 6,000 rows and 12 columns. I tried:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET_KEY","Sheet1!A:C"),"select Col1")
```

The result is `#REF!` and when I hover over the cell there is no additional information.

I also tried the IMPORTRANGE formula separately and it's loading the data correctly. I tried the exact same query in a new tab in the source sheet:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:C,"select A")
```

and the data was loaded successfully, however I need to run the query formula in a new Google sheet.

Comment: Have you tried to make ImportRange formula only? `IMPORTRANGE("SHEET_KEY","Sheet1!A:C")`

Comment: Also, hovering over the cell with an error should give a bit more information.

Comment: No additional information on hover; importrange works separately

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but it could be some sort of glich.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236270/google-spreadsheet-import-range-ref-error-randomly) may help you.

I had similiar problems. I tried doing this:

1. refreshing page
2. changing range in the formula to force it recalculate: `"Sheet1!A:C"` → `"Sheet1!A1:C6000"`
3. Also [found smart way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21430049/5372400) to make it with iferror: `iferror(IMPORTRANGE("SHEET_KEY","Sheet1!A:C"))`

If this won't help, please give example file.